# Converting keras to opencv: readNetFromTensorflow doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, computer-vision

I want to convert a keras model to opencv. My steps were the following:

```
#######Model######

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(200, 200, 3), filters=96, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=4, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(LayerNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(LayerNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(LayerNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=17, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3) # Callback for earlystopping
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

then I converted the model to an .pb file

```
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()
layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]

tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir="./models",
                  name="model.pb",
                  as_text=True)
```

But when I try to load the .pb file into opencv by using:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('models/model.pb')
```

the following error occurs:

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:2799: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: sequential/layer_normalization_2/Shape in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::connect'




[ERROR:0@0.108] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp (3159) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::parseNode DNN/TF: Can't parse layer for node='sequential/layer_normalization_2/strided_slice_3' of type='StridedSlice'. Exception: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:2799: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: sequential/layer_normalization_2/Shape in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::connect'
```

I really hope someone can help me

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d8f/tf_cls_tutorial_dnn_conversion.html

Comment: Alternatively, convert your Keras model to ONNX and use that for inference in OpenCV.